# How to mount NFS export on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, mount, freebsd, nfs

I have FreeBSD (`test.local`) box configured as NFS server. And I'm trying to mount its NFS sharing form my mac (`hhmm.local`)

```
/nfs     hhmm.local
```

`/nfs` has `777` permission.

And I checked from mac that it's working,

```
hhmm:~ Eonil$ showmount -e test.local
Exports list on test.local:
/nfs                           test.local
hhmm:~ Eonil$
```

But when I try to mount it,

```
hhmm:~ Eonil$ mount_nfs test.local:/nfs ~/nfs
mount_nfs: can't access /nfs: Permission denied
hhmm:~ Eonil$
```

Wow. I cannot figure out why this doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: I was seeing **permission denied** on the **AWS storage gateway** NFS file share, issue was that my IP was outside the the allowed share access client CIDR range

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with `mount_nfs: can't access /: Permission denied` on OS X 10.6.8 and even with the `resvport` option it still failed however modifying the nfs server export mount to use the `insecure` option worked.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with this blog post:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apple-mac-osx-nfs-mount-command-tutorial/

Core solution was giving an option `resvport` on mounting option. NFS volume mounted magically!

Comment: Was having this same issue; the `resvport` option works fine if you only plan on mounting via the CLI. If you want to mount via Mac OS X's finder, you need to add the `insecure` option on the server side, as @Cas mentions. There is no way to specify `resvport` via finder, and the ability to mount and use advanced options has been removed from "Disk Utility", so it seems as the server side fix is the only viable solution for GUI connecting.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that host 10.18.14.27 running NFS has shared path-

```
/home/siddiquim
```

On your mac, Try:

```
$ sudo mount -o resvport,rw  -t nfs  10.18.14.27:/home/siddiquim folder_207
```

Verify that contents are visible:

```
$ ls -ltr folder_207
```

Answer (score 1):

my problem solved, NFS to mac High Sierra 10.13
Change on server NFS /etc/exports, put your client IP.
Ex: ip server:192.168.1.2  client ip:192.168.1.10
on server, sudo vi, /export/www   192.168.1.10(rw,insecure,root_squash,no_subtree_check,async)

Comment: As long as the server can resolve the client’s hostname (i.e., `ping hhmm.local` works),  there’s no reason for this to make a difference.

Comment: Had this same issue at my work almost a whole year ago and completely forgot how to fix it. Thanks for pointing me back in the right direction.