# Mac OS X & Linux: mount_nfs: can't access /nfs: Permission denied

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, network-shares, nfs

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 NFS server and I have an iMac NFS client running OS X 10.6.8. I believe I have everything set up properly, yet I still get this error on the Mac:

```
mount_nfs: can't access /nfs: Permission denied
```

My exports on the Linux server uses the `insecure` option like this:

```
/export/home/me/        192.168.100.132(rw,subtree_check,insecure,nohide)
```

Where 192.168.100.132 is the address of my Mac.

I have even tried using `-o resvport` on the Mac (in addition to `insecure` on Linux) and I still get the same error as above.

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport 192.168.100.1:/home/me /Users/me/mount
```

Here is the output of `showmount`:

```
# showmount -e 192.168.100.1

Export list for 192.168.100.1:
/export/home/me 192.168.100.132
....
```

I have reviewed this similar question:
[How to mount NFS export on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/254339/how-to-mount-nfs-export-on-mac-os-x)

And I have reviewed this frequently recommended tutorial:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apple-mac-osx-nfs-mount-command-tutorial/

I still can't find a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm seeing the same error. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, it is working for me. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mount command needs to look like this:

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.100.1:/export/home/me /Users/me/mount
```

You can alternatively enter `192.168.100.1/export/home/me` in the Disk Utility NFS mounts dialog.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was missing export in my cmd

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had my wifi on, and my computer was wired too, when I turned off the wifi, access was restored